# How to delete same row across 2 sheets in Gsheets?

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

I have a Gsheet where if I need to delete a row that contains the text 'none' on Sheet1, it will also delete the same row (or range of rows) on Sheet2.

I've tried the following code which will delete the row on Sheet1, but I can't get it to delete the corresponding row on Sheet2

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
              SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i]; 
    if (row[9] == 'none') { 
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
};
```

The expected result is to delete the same row on both sheets, but at the moment it is only deleting on Sheet1.

Thanks!

And if the 'none' text was in a different column on Sheet1 than Sheet2, what would I do? I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var rows = sheet1.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i]; 
    if (row[9] == 'none') { 
      sheet1.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
    if (row[10] == 'none') {   
      sheet2.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
};}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create two seperate variables for the two seperate sheets:

```
function sort() { 
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var rows = sheet1.getDataRange(); 
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); 
  var values = rows.getValues(); 
  var rowsDeleted = 0; 

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) { 
    var row = values[i]; 
    if (row[9] == 'none') { 
      sheet1.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      sheet2.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++; 
    } 
  } 
};
```